# C# UdpClient does not return from EndReceive

Tags: c#, udpclient

I am using an c# UdpClient to receive data via udp. Everything works fine, but after a while the method receiveClient does not return.

First aI thought it is a synchronisation problem so I enclosed the shared resource (lastPackage) with a lock, but this did not help.

I debugged the program (which was hard, due to the asynchron receiveing) and finally found out that the method endReceive does not return. The udp source does continue to send the packages.

Below I have printed the relevant program parts.

```
public class UDPSocket {

private IPEndPoint receiveEndPoint;
private UdpClient receiveClient;

private byte[] lastPackage;

private bool unhandledPackage;//shared resource

private Dictionary<string, string> agentsMap;

public UDPSocket(string sendIp, int sendPort, int receivePort){     

    receiveEndPoint = new IPEndPoint (IPAddress.Any, receivePort);
    receiveClient = new UdpClient (receiveEndPoint);
    singleton.receiveClient.BeginReceive(new AsyncCallback(singleton.ReceiveCallback), null);

    unhandledPackage = false;

    agentsMap = new Dictionary<string, string> ();
}

public void Update () {//is called once per second

    if (unhandledPackage) {
        string rawString = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(lastPackage);
        agentsMap = Parser.parseString(rawString);

        unhandledPackage = false;
        receiveClient.BeginReceive(new AsyncCallback(ReceiveCallback), null);
    }
}

public string getEmotion(string id){

    string emotion;
    if(!agentsMap.TryGetValue(id, out emotion)){
        return "No connection";
    }
    return emotion;
}

public void OnDestroy()
{
    if (receiveClient != null) {
        receiveClient.Close ();
    }
}

public void ReceiveCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
{
    lastPackage = receiveClient.EndReceive(ar, ref receiveEndPoint);//DOES NOT RETURN FROM THIS METHOD CALL
    unhandledPackage = true;
}
```

I have simplified the program to show only possibly relevant parts.
I would be thankfull, if somebody could help me.

Regards, 
Jan

Comment: What is `singleton.receiveClient`?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using .net 4.5, simply use the async&await keywords, this way:

```
    private static async void Foo(int port)
    {
        UdpClient udpClient=new UdpClient(port);
        UdpReceiveResult result = await udpClient.ReceiveAsync();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

`EndReceive` will block if the async operation has not finished.

I assume that `receiveClient` in `ReceiveCallback` is another `receiveClient` as that was used with `BeginReceive`. So make sure you use the same instance.